# Error when compiling a java projec

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

I imported a java swing project into netbeans 6.9 and when I am trying to clean and build the project following message displayed, and I can't run the application though it is compiled, please help.

......

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

....

I am getting following error when running the application once I build the application with the above error,

```
org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap$LookupException: string conversion failed: resource createNewSrn.Action.icon, type interface javax.swing.Icon
        at org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap.getObject(ResourceMap.java:578)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap.getIcon(ResourceMap.java:787)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.initActionProperties(ApplicationAction.java:449)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.<init>(ApplicationAction.java:252)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationActionMap.addAnnotationActions(ApplicationActionMap.java:147)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationActionMap.<init>(ApplicationActionMap.java:81)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ActionManager.createActionMapChain(ActionManager.java:64)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ActionManager.getActionMap(ActionManager.java:169)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationContext.getActionMap(ApplicationContext.java:290)
        at Manufacturing.frmSRN.initComponents(frmSRN.java:1289)
        at Manufacturing.frmSRN.<init>(frmSRN.java:59)
        at COMMON.FrmMDI.butitadd3ActionPerformed(FrmMDI.java:3684)
        at COMMON.FrmMDI.access$7200(FrmMDI.java:60)
        at COMMON.FrmMDI$49.actionPerformed(FrmMDI.java:904)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: org.jdesktop.application.ResourceConverter$ResourceConverterException: couldn't find Icon resource "/images/folder_new.png" string: "/images/folder_new.png"
        at org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap.loadImageIcon(ResourceMap.java:1378)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap.access$000(ResourceMap.java:93)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap$IconStringConverter.parseString(ResourceMap.java:1465)
        at org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap.getObject(ResourceMap.java:573)
        ... 51 more
```

Comment: Is your Netbeans using Java 5 or below?

Comment: He means your JDK version, not your Netbeans version.

Comment: The messages you mention are notifications/warnings, not errors. The "Note: ..." messages mean that compilation does take place (at least partially). Can you elaborate on "I can't run the application though it is compiled"?

Comment: @Raghuram-> I am using java 1.7

Comment: Once I run this application I get following error, org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap$LookupException: String conversion failed: resource saveSrn.Action.icon, type interface javax.swing.icon

Answer (score 0):

Tell NetBeans that you want to compile using JDK 6; it should assume that you're using those language features.

I'm not sure where to do it, but it looks like it's assuming a JDK other than version 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDK 7 to compile a project but specify source or target to be an earlier version (like 1.6 => Java 6), it warns you that you should really make the bootclasspath point to the Java 6 libraries to make sure that the code will actually be able to run on Java 1.6 (eg to make sure that you are not using classes or methods introduced in Java 6).

So either use source/target 1.7, or compile with JDK 6, or configure your build to set the bootclasspath to that of Java 6.